Ability to stop a generic DOM event, which is grid related and reissue after a specified interval or in response to a server callback
Is there a centralized way (or even not strictly centralized one) to capture a slickgrid event (such beforeeditcell) then kill  it (saving event data) then reissue it upon a callback?
Of course i can do this via std DOM events but i would have preferred a more grid related and less intrusive way)
Basically, in a subscripted event handler i need to :

store event data
cancel the event (kill)
after a call back is received i need to resend the event with the  stored event  data

... it is a question. i did not  expecting other than a answer
